# What is the difference between re.sub and String replace in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, replace, substring

I'm trying to solve this [problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/battlesimulation) on Kattis. I have come up with my first solution:

```
str_to_replace = {"RBL": "C", "RLB": "C", "LBR": "C", "LRB": "C", "BRL": "C", "BLR": "C"}
uin = input().upper()
for key, value in str_to_replace.items():
    uin = uin.replace(key, value)
uin = uin.replace("R", "S")
uin = uin.replace("B", "K")
uin = uin.replace("L", "H")
print(uin)
```

Submitted but the judge said wrong answer in a hidden test case.

After googling for a while, I tried re.sub and it works.

```
uin = input().upper()
uin = re.sub('RBL|RLB|BRL|BLR|LRB|LBR', 'C', uin)
uin = uin.replace("R", "S")
uin = uin.replace("B", "K")
uin = uin.replace("L", "H")
print(uin)
```

I'm trying to figure out which test case I have missed and what are the differences between them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Regular expressions are, surprise, more efficient? Worth checking out [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) as well.

Comment: @tadman If it's about efficiency I believe the judge should have said Memory Limit Exceeded or Time Limit Exceeded instead but I think I missed something and couldn't figure out where

Comment: The regex version is more readable, but again, check out `translate()` which might help.

Comment: Doing different replacements one after another definitely has some room to differ from doing one regex all at a time if any of the values you're matching overlap in the string you're operating on.

Comment: @tadman Thanks I will check it out seems helpful in my case too

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have a feel that as well but I'm still trying to figure out which case it fall to so I won't make the same mistake again in the future

Comment: yeah, my instinct is that the issue is overlaps

Comment: a difference could be also that with regex, if used properly, it could done in a single statement

Comment: Consider "LRBL". The loop will first replace "RBL" since that is first in the list giving you "LC". But since "LRB" is first in the string, it should be "CL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Johnny's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75620544/what-is-the-difference-between-re-sub-and-string-replace-in-python-3#comment133412370_75620544) nailed it.

Basically, the `re.sub` version makes one pass, processing all combos from front to back. So a substring like `"LRBL"` will match `"LRB"` and replace it with `"C"`, then move on to `"L"` with a result of `"CL"`.

On the other hand, the `.replace()` version uses a loop, so it processes the string in multiple passes. For the `"LRBL"` example, if `"RBL"` -> `"C"` happened to be processed before `"LRB"` -> `"C"`, then the output would be `"LC"` rather than `"CL"`.

The other `.replace()` calls look suspicious, because they would do transitive replacements if there was any overlap. Luckily there isn't such a case here, so they're just a bit inefficient.

If you use a function for your replacer and add `.` to the regex to handle any single-letter remnants after trying to locate the chunks of 3, you can do it in a single pass:

```py
import re

d = dict(B="K", L="H", R="S")
print(re.sub("RBL|RLB|LBR|LRB|BLR|BRL|.", lambda m: d.get(m[0], "C"), input()))
```